# Function overriding array and returning empty

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two arrays of objects;

1. offers
2. redemptions

I want to check if the offers array has a property of `"id"` that matches a property of `"offer_id"` in redemptions. If it does then I will set the property of `"used"` in that specific offer object to `true`.

So far I have come up with the below, however, when I reset the offers within `checkUsedRedemptions` it is giving me back an `[]`.

### CODE

```
const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);
const [redemptions, setRedemptions] = useState([]);

const getData = async (uid) => {
  Promise.all([
    fetchVenue(),
    fetchVenueOffers(id),
    fetchUserData(uid),
    fetchUserRedemptionsForVenue(uid, id),
  ])
    .then(() => {
      // CALLING FUNCTION HERE AS IT ENSURES OFFERS AND REDEMPTIONS NOT []
      checkUsedRedemptions();
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    });
};

const fetchVenueOffers = async (id) => {
  const offers = await getVenueOffers(id);
  setOffers(offers);
};

const fetchUserRedemptionsForVenue = async (uid, id) => {
  const redemptions = await getUserRedemptionsForVenue(uid, id);
  setRedemptions(redemptions);
};

const checkUsedRedemptions = () => {
  for (const offer of offers) {
    for (const redemption of redemptions) {
      if (offer.id === redemption.offer_id) {
        offer.used = true;
      }
    }
  }
  // CORRECT OFFERS IN LOG;
  console.log("HERE ARE THE OFFERS", offers);
  // OFFERS === [] IN SET OFFERS???
  // setOffers(offers);
};
```

### UPDATE

```
const checkUsedRedemptions = () => {
  console.log(offers)
  // OFFERS HERE IS []
}
```

Comment: @GrafiCode this is React code; `offers` is declared somewhere not included in what's posted.

Comment: @Pointy I've updated the Q with state.

Comment: The thing is, calling `setOffers()` with the content fetched will change the value *in the state*, but it won't cause the value of the variable `offers` to change, will it? It'll still be the original `[]` that you used to initialize it, not the new array built from the fetched content.

Comment: (I could be wrong; I'm not a React person, but I don't see how that would work in JavaScript terms.)

Comment: @Pointy unsure if it’s doing that. I’m not sure it should though as the console log returns the correct values for the array and it’s just a matter of using the set method to pass the data to.

Comment: Okay so the problem is that when I first call checkUsedRedemptions the offers are empty.